# Яндекс карты. Маршрутизация

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Как получить координаты точки B(конечная точка) используя панель маршрутизации.
По примеру из [песочницы](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/deliveryCalculator)

Answer (score 1):

Это реализуется таким способом:

```
route.getWayPoints().get(1).geometry.getCoordinates()
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/3azs92tw/